# Use accounts on the device permission - please clarify when needed

Tags: permissions

I've read this: [What can an app do with the "USE ACCOUNTS ON THE DEVICE" permission?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38369/what-can-an-app-do-with-the-use-accounts-on-the-device-permission)?

In the main answer (by Dan) it's said:

> The AccountManager then asks
>   you if you want the requesting app (YouTube) to be able to use the
>   requested account (Google account). This might be in a dialog that
>   appears over the app, or in a notification.

However, upon installing something, e.g. Facebook (which adds facebook account as I understand) and starting to use it, I don't remember some system message asking me to grant access to facebook account to facebook app.
Facebook app can post on facebook w/out using facebook account?

Comment: Facebook app provides and owns that account I'd say :) So please also check the counter-part of the question you've linked: [What does permission “MANAGE_ACCOUNTS” mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44293/16575)

Comment: @ Izzy, thank you. I've read post I mentioned more closely and see answer. should i better delete my question? Also, maybe you know answer to mine other one: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151803/use-accounts-on-the-device-permission-can-access-token-be-used-by-other-app-et ?

Comment: If the answer is already given there, this question here should either be deleted or closed as duplicate. Maybe the latter would be the better idea, with you providing a comment here clearly pointing to that answer. As for your other question: No specific insights on *how* operations with that token work – but using it elsewhere would first need that app to reveal the token, right? // PS: Did you check with our [permissions tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info) already? Lots of useful information linked from there :)

Comment: @Izzy, thank you. how do I mark it as duplicate? Also, maybe you can help w/out me creating other question - I have skype on two phones. on 5.1 I see skype account in settings, however on 4.4 there is no skype account (see viber, whatsapp etc.).  Why could it be?

Comment: Different question, and I cannot answer that. Please post it separately.