# How to lock down WhatsApp permissions?

Tags: custom-roms, whatsapp-messenger, privacy

A number of friends are using WhatsApp for communication. So I'm thinking about installing it. However when I read the [question about its permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/71802/174599) I'm asking myself if there is a possibility to lock down the permissions.

I'd like to do have a solution where some permissions are always allowed, some are always blocked and some are blocked, but can be enabled on a temporary basis (like a popup menu which asks). Is this somehow possible? Do some custome ROMs have such a feature? If yes, which?

Comment: CyanogenMod has its **Privacy Manager**, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Donkey Guard](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-donkeyguard-security-management-t2831556) the Xposed Framework module from which you can manage permission for apps.

DonkeyGuard allows blocking access for any installed application on your phone to the following data separately:

- device_id
- phone_number
- sim_serial_number
- subscriber_id
- incoming_call_number
- outgoing_call_number
- gps_and_network_location
- impi_impu
- cell_info
- accounts
- accounts_credentials
- read_contacts
- read_call_log
- call_phone
- read_calendar
- receive_sms
- send_sms
- receive_mms
- send_mms - not implemented in alpha
- record_audio
- use_camera
- read_bookmarks
- wifi_info
- switch_mobile_network_state
- switch_wifi_state
- sim_info
- network_info
- android_id
- access_media
- read_external_storage - not implemented in alpha
- write_calendar
- write_call_log
- write_contacts
- write_bookmarks
- write_external_storage - not implemented in alpha
- account_authenticator
- read_sms
- write_sms
- read_mms
- write_mms
- network_state

## Edit:

Alternative Module : [Xprivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) (suggested by @beeshyams)

Comment: Perhaps you missed the fact at XDA that the module doesn't seem to be supported any more? Suggesting alternate like Xpiracy may be more helpful (haven't checked that lately though)