# Whatsapp permission to record when calling

Tags: calls

I can understand the request for the App to access to the Mic for sending the voice in a phone call. But why is it necessary to say "record"? Recording is a separate function and the caller's choice. It is scary to think that Whatsapp is recording and storing your calls somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help understanding Whatsapp's permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/71802/help-understanding-whatsapps-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

I think record comes with Mic permissions, the calls are not recorded, at least not by Whatsapp. The record permission is for sending voice messages. Also Whatsapp voice calls like its text message service is end to end encrypted. That means that only your phone and the recipient's phone can decrypt the information being passed.

Answer (score 1):

> why is it necessary to say "record"? Recording is a separate function

Not as far as the permission system is concerned. Once an app can receive the audio from the microphone, it can transmit it, record it, or do whatever it likes with it. There's no way to give an app access to the microphone without it being able to record and store the audio. By giving the app permission, you have to trust the app to only use the audio data in the way you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a particular permission if you would like to let WhatsApp use your phone microphone (for example: for Audio recording, WhatsApp calls). 
If you don’t want to use these features, you can simply deny mic permission and keep using the WhatsApp text chat feature.

Whatsapp asks for record permission to use the microphone and record audio. Yes, WhatsApp records audio from your mic and stores them into

```
/Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/Sent
```

then later your recorded audio is being sent to another person.